# How to pass php variable value to div's iframe using href

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

```html
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM `notification` where `Status`='1'  && `ownerid`='$userid' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$nid=$row['notifid'];

$pr="select * from `Swap` where `notifid`='$nid'";
$prm=mysql_query($pr);
$prow=mysql_fetch_assoc($prm);
$rid=$prow['Requesterid'];

$query1="select * from `myuser` where `Userid`='$rid'";
//echo $query1;
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
$row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
$rname=$row1['Firstname'];
//echo $rname;
?>

<div style="width:100%; background: rgb(228, 228, 228);margin: 20px;padding: 20px;">
<h1>A New Swapping Request from <?php echo $rname; ?></h1>
Your sweater is choose for swapping.....you want to give permission?? 
  <div onclick="clicked(this);" id="<?php echo $nid; ?>">VIEW REQUEST</div>
</div>
<?php
$count++;
}
?>
  <div id="light" class="white_content" style="  height: auto;">
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" style="background: #EAEAEA; padding: 5px 7px; color: #000; float: right;" onclick="confirmno()">X</a>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked(item) {
     document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
     var a = $(item).attr("id");
   }
  </script>            
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
 <iframe width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="confirmed.php?x="+a> </iframe>  
  </div>

 </div>
```

hi,
here i want to pass unique php variable via href/anything else into  for i frame src to pass.after see numbers of tutorials i get the value of $nid in $(item).attr("id"); but how to pass this value to  i try u can see in my code..but its not working plz help

Comment: Try using passing nid to onclick js function

Comment: can u help me in detail,i am not so much aware about js.

Answer (score 0):

If js is in separate file (.js), then it's not parsed by PHP and therefore PHP tags won't work there.

In this case You could solve this by 2 scenarios:

1) Move function declaration to file that is parsed by PHP (like second block of Your code, where this function is called)

2) Add input parameter to "confirmno" function. Parameter sets "nid" value and it is given by PHP file (instead of 'onclick="confirmno()' You would use 'onclick="confirmno()'.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmno(nid) {
    var con=confirm('You want keep this?');
    if (con == true) {
      window.location="notification.php";
    } else {
      window.location="confirmed1.php?nid=" + nid;
    }
}
</script>

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" style="background: #EAEAEA; padding: 5px 7px; color: #000; float: right;" onclick="confirmno(<?php echo $nid; ?>)">X</a>
```

Comment: dear,you r not understand my question mylink is VIEW REQUEST. i want passing $nid to <div id="light" ><iframe src="this place" > as u can see in my code

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood Your question. Could You be more specific what is iframe src after first click?

Comment: on first click show popup for half sec without complete data.then redirect back to page.then we do click then work perfect